# FindControl getting wrong control in my recursive method

Tags: asp.net, web-controls

I use the following method to find a control on an asp.net page recursively:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Searches recursively for a server control with the specified id parameter.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="start">The start.</param>
    /// <param name="id">The id.</param>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="Control"/></returns>
    public static Control FindControl(Control start, string id)
    {

        Control foundControl;
        if (start == null)
            return null;

        foundControl = start.FindControl(id);
        if (foundControl != null)
            return foundControl;

        foreach (Control c in start.Controls)
        {
            foundControl = FindControl(c, id);
            if (foundControl != null)
                return foundControl;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I hit a problem because it was returning the wrong control. I tracked the problem down to the standard FindControl method, and fixed it by checking that the id of the control returned did actually match the one requested like this:

```
    foundControl = start.FindControl(id);
        if (foundControl != null && foundControl.ID == id)
            return foundControl;
```

My question is why does start.FindControl(id) ever return a control that does not match the id requested?

Answer (score 2):

I use

```
static class ControlExtension
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(this Control parent)
        {
            foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
            {
                yield return control;
                foreach (Control descendant in control.GetAllControls())
                {
                    yield return descendant;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and call

```
var foundControl =  Page.GetAllControls().Where(c => c.ID = id);
```

EDIT:

maybe instead of calling this to start the search

```
 foundControl = start.FindControl(id);
```

you should start with

```
foundControl = FindControl(start, id);
```

Comment: Yeah, doesn't use FindControl at all, looks very powerful, finding controls on any criteria I like. Unfortunately I'm stuck in a place that doesn't want to upgrade to C#3.0 so no lambda expressions yet....  I could still rewrite my method in C#2.0 to just check whether ID matches without using FindControl, but I was curious about how FindControl could return a control that clearly does not match the ID specified by the parameter.

Comment: Re your edit. I need foundControl = start.FindControl(id); or some other means of identifying the correct control, otherwise it will always be null.

Comment: I could rewrite it to just compare the ids inside the loop i.e. if (c.id == id) return c; I was really just curious about the unexpected behaviour of FindControl and wondered if anyone else had come across the problem